# How to hook lifecycle events from root App component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, hook, lifecycle

The structure of the app:

```
src/
|-- App.vue
|-- components/
    |-- MyComponent.vue
    |-- OtherComponent.vue
```

If I do, in MyComponent.vue

```
// MyComponent.vue

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  methods: {
    mounted() {
      alert('MyComponent mounted')
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected — an alert box is triggered when the component is mounted.

However, if I do the exact same thing in App.vue:

```
// App.vue

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue'
import OtherComponent from './components/OtherComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    MyComponent,
    OtherComponent
  },
  methods: {
    mounted() {
      alert('app mounted')
    }
  }
}
```

**Then nothing happens**. I've tried with `created`, `mounted`, I've also try to wrap the `alert()` call into `this.$nextTick({ ... })` — no success.

My problem is: I want something to happen (in this example, `alert('app mounted')`) once the child components have been mounted, because this "thing" needs to have all components mounted before executing.

Is it possible to hook a lifecycle event (ideally, `mounted`) in the App component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All lifecycle methods need not to be declared within methods.

Should be as below.

```
// App.vue

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue'
import OtherComponent from './components/OtherComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    MyComponent,
    OtherComponent
  },
   mounted() {
      alert('app mounted')
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
```

For more details read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Comment: interesting! thanks. Any idea why it works in components but not in App then?

Comment: Can u add template code of myComponent.vue?As normally it doesn't works like this.

Answer (score 1):

**`mounted` is life cycle method of vue component**. don't put it in methods.

Change

```
// MyComponent.vue

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  methods: {
    mounted() {
      alert('MyComponent mounted')
    }
  }
}
```

To

```
// MyComponent.vue

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  methods: {
  },
  mounted() {
    alert('MyComponent mounted')
  }
}
```